# How to add a disclaimer to forwarded messages to outside domains in Exchange 2013?

Tags: postfix, exchange-2013, mail-forwarding

I would like to implement some kind of filter to add a disclaimer message within emails forwarded to outside domains.

Today we have some users that setup filters to forward messages to external mail servers, as example @gmail addresses. So this kind of forward should be marked with the disclaimer message. Not the normal fwd messages.

We have a Postfix mailfiltering gateway too, if it's simpler to implement this on the mail filter, it could be a viable option.

What would be the best approach to handle this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [transport rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351127%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I can't find anything useful at transport rules to match users that REDIRECT messages to outside relays. I think it's just a single rule, if TO and RESENT-TO fields are equal it's a redirect.